# Field due to objects if inverse square law does not hold

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, symmetry, integration

There is a hypothetical question about what will happen to the field of objects if inverse square law is replaced with something else.

For example, it can be proved that if force is proportional to inverse of distance then the field inside a ring will be zero. The way to do it is same as you prove for shell in case of inverse square law.

Now, what concepts can be used to find the direction of field inside a charged shell or in the plane of a disk or proportionality of field due to an infinite plane.

Answer (score 1):

For a force that scales as $\sim1/r$ the potential takes the form
$$V(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x'})=\alpha\log|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x'}|,$$
so the potential of a spherical shell of radius $R$ and unit charge density is given by the integral

$$ \begin{aligned} V&=\alpha R^2\int\log|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x'}| d\Omega\\ &=\pi\alpha R^2\int^{1}_{-1}\log|R^2+r^2-2rRu|du\\&=\pi\alpha R^2
\left[-2+2(1-\frac{R^2+r^2}{2rR})\log|R-r|+\frac{(R+r)^2}{rR}\log|R+r|\right].\end{aligned}$$ The electric field is given by the negative of the derivative of the potential with respect to $r$. $E_r$ actually takes the simple form $$\frac{E_r}{\pi\alpha R^2}=-\frac{2}{r}+\frac{r^2-R^2}{r^2R}\log\left|\frac{r-R}{r+R}\right|.$$

Here's a plot of the electric field, with its small and large $r$ behavior showed in dotted lines.

[image]

Comment: [Note](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange): “If someone posts an answer to a homework-type question that gives away a complete or near-complete solution, in most cases it will be temporarily deleted.”

Comment: I may be understanding it wrong but won't field outside the shell will be directed away from the shell?

Comment: Also, this is not a homework-type question and I don't have to give the solution to anyone. I just want to develop my understanding and came across this question and was stuck with a part of it.

Comment: I plotted this with $\alpha>0$, for electrostatics (or this version of electrostatics) you would have $\alpha<0$ and the field will be directed away from the shell.

Comment: Okay. My point is field will be towards center inside the shell and away outside the shell. The direction will flip at the boundary of the shell.

Comment: Appears not to be the case, the field never changes sign.